# Module Based Application, Execute code OnExit?

Tags: vb.net, events

I have a small VB.Net application that is marked as a Windows forms application however, there are no forms.

Everything is driven by a module. This was done to eliminate any form of interface (form, console window, etc.). I have a new need to execute a bit of code just prior to the application closing however, I cannot seem to find a suitable event to attach to.

Whether the app closes due to an unhandled exception (of course this never happens..) or closed via task manager, I need this code to execute. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Task Manager does not ask nicely, it will shoot your program in the head and kill you dead.  No notification.  Maybe it isn't a very good idea to give the user a hard time to get your program to quit.  Create a service instead or use NotifyIcon.

Answer (score 0):

Try subscribing to the Application's exit event. In Main (or whatever code is called on application start), add a handler:

```
    AddHandler Application.ApplicationExit, AddressOf OnApplicationExit
```

Then define a handler to run when the application shuts down.

```
'Application Exit hander
Private Sub OnApplicationExit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Try
        ' Ignore any errors that might occur while closing the file handle.

    Catch
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have already tried this and it does not fire when the app is shutdown via task manager.

Comment: That's true about the task manager. I don't know of any way to run code in that situation.